# Save and display ui_component's custom field

Tags: event-observer, magento2.3, multi-source-inventory

I've added custom text box to source form using below code.

```
<field name="delivery_time" formElement="input" sortOrder="70">
            <settings>
                <dataType>text</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Delivery Time</label>
            </settings>
</field>
```

To save this field value I'm observing event `controller_action_inventory_populate_source_with_data`.

I tried below in observer,

```
$request = $observer->getEvent()->getRequest();
$requestData = $request->getParam('general', []);
$deliveryTime =  $requestData['delivery_time'];
```

I tried below code but it's not working,

```
$request->setParam('delivery_time',$deliveryTime);

$request->setPostValue('delivery_time',$deliveryTime);
```

I've created new column with **delivery_time** to table.

None of above is working Any idea ?

Any help will be appreciate. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try this: $request->setDeliveryTime($deliveryTime);

Comment: There's no method like 'setDeliveryTime' do it will return error with call to undefined method.....

Comment: are you sure this is a magento 2.3 version?

Comment: Yes @magefms It's 2.3 CE and form is Sources under stores.

Comment: can you post your whole observer code

Comment: can you try this `$request = $observer->getEvent()->getRequest();
        //$requestData = $request->getParam('general', []);
        $requestData = $request->getPost()->toArray();
        $deliveryTime =  $requestData['general']['delivery_time'];

        $request->setPostValue('delivery_time',$deliveryTime);`

Comment: Already tried your way, But not working.

Comment: @magefms, Why dont you give a try to reproduce it in your project ?

Comment: can't reproduce it, too little info

Comment: @magefms, Not little, Let me try again, I've added new field to source form, Under stores->Inventory->sources. Using xml file, and want to save field to DB table inventory_source where all other fields are getting stored that's it. What else you thing missing ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save this you have to create extension attribute for your entity.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/attributes.html

Check above to know how to create those.

Than you can use in observer like, setter and getter methods like `getDeliveryTime` and `setDeliveryTime`.

Hope it will help to solve your issue.